# Unable to locate the requested element: By.xpath: //*[@id="SF-Refresh"]

Tags: xpath, automation, apex

I have been trying to get my Automation Tests up and Running but keep running into some Xpath Errors. I am having 5 errors all with missing/not being able to locate the Xpath that I have wrote. I need to have my test click on a "Refresh" Button located in a data table that is located on the Web page. Button instead of clicking on the button I get the error below. The ID of the button is "SF-Refresh" .

```
@When("I click refresh button")
@Given("I click refresh button")
@Then("I click refresh button")
public void clickRefreshButton() {
    By linkSelect = new By.ByXPath("//*[@id=\"SF-Refresh\"]");   
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LightningButton.click(linkSelect);

}
```

Error:
Unable to locate the requested element: By.xpath: //*[@id="SF-Refresh"]

Comment: What is the exact error message? What if you don't scape the doble quots like in `//*[@id='SF-Refresh']`?

Comment: share your HTML code

Answer (score 0):

There is few possible error as below:

1) The Xpath is might wrong or same Xpath return multiple elements, the xpath must return one element only if you are using `findElement`

2) The element is might not load properly yet or not ready for action use below:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id="SF-Refresh"]")));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id="SF-Refresh"]")));
    LightningButton.click(linkSelect);
```